# Creating an image in PHP that sizes its self to the text

Tags: php, gd

I'm trying to dynamically create an image with some text in PHP. The problem that I'm running into is, every way I've seen to do this starts with:
    imagecreate($h, $w);

And then draws the text to the image. I want to have the image be sized around the text. Preferably, I'd like a max-width too where the text will wrap and the image will "expand" downward, but I think I can figure that out on my own. I (clearly) don't have a lot of php gd experience, so any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: You'd have to find a metric to "predict" the text size, based on font type and size, not an easy task. Sure you cannot simply modify an existing image by means of css?

Comment: If you really want to create an "image", then probably the best approach is to chose the vector format. That allows much more flexibility than raster formats. Read: take a look at SVG graphics.

Comment: Or... you know... just use HTML and CSS to size and style your text according to its container.

Comment: For some context, I needed it to be an image because I was having some students type in SQL queries. After N failed attempts, I wanted to show them the answer and still require them to type it in. Obviously if I just displayed text, they could copy and paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after doing some more digging, I found imagefontwidth (and height). Using these I can calculate the size of the string, and there for set the image size accordingly. Thanks for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just do it in the rendered HTML with CSS styling as an alternative to using GD:

```
background-size: contain;
```

Will fit the background image to the content while maintaining the image's aspect ratio.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jimbo2150/7z1c2aaf/12/)